# Are there more agile testing techniques like test jumpers, mob testing etc.?

Tags: manual-testing, agile-testing, agile

In our project we want to move away from the *regular* testing methods (e.g. ISTQB specification based testing) and we want to expand our testing technique with agile testing techniques. Who knows agile testing techniques? Are there more ideas & suggestions?

Based from my experience we have following agile testing techniques:

- Test jumpers (e.g. [Test Jumpers Explanation)](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/1372)
- Exploratory testing
- Paired exploratory testing (e.g. [Paired Exploratory testing](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/598))
- Session based testing

Are there **more** agile testing techniques which could help in our case? 
Any help is appreciated! Note we are testing mainly Web-Browser Applications.

Comment: What type of service are you testing ? Is it UI , API ? Commercial ? In-house ? . As you know testing is context depended , so explain your context

Comment: We are mainly testing from the business department logic - means frontend UI. The developer are doing automated tests (e.g. Unit Test) and we - as business department doing more exploratory way what the "user" sees

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure true Agile testing techniques exist. Some testing techniques are used and work well within the Agile context, others don't.

Common agile quality practises, part of the [technical excelence](https://less.works/less/technical-excellence/index.html) princible:

- Specification by Example
- Test Driven Development
- Whole team approach
- Unit testing
- Continuous delivery

Some techniques that might help:

- A/B testing and testing in production

Comment: Great points. +1  I do wonder if Unit testing and AB testing are agile specifically.  I mean are they done in waterfall too sometimes? Not sure.

Comment: Unit testing got popular with Kent Beck and his part in eXtreme Programming, which was one of the early Agile methods. Ab-testing is about getting faster feedback. The techniques the OP suggest can also be uses in the non Agile context.

Comment: Thanks a not Niels! The points "Whole team approach" and "Specification by example" are good hints! I will try to consider them in our exploratory testing way! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Agile testing relies on a number of key concepts.  Two of them are:

## The Test pyramid

This provides a guide for having a large number of good unit tests, a medium number of integration tests and a small number of the slow and brittle (by their nature) UI tests.

[image]

## Agile Testing Quadrants

Similar to the pyramid, another representation of the various different types of testing.  This however is better at relating them to the business needs and goals as shown on the sides.

[image]

The best guide I know of that covers this in detail?

[image]

Practices that are key are: BDD and TDD

### BDD - Behvior driven development

Using *high level* tests (that fail first) to drive the development and the design of the application code that will make them pass

## TDD - Test Driven Development

I often prefer to refer to this as 'Test Driven *Design*'.  Using tests to make sure that every component works.  All external services should be mocked and stubbed out (network, disk, database, screen, etc).

Comment: There is a new version of the Agile Testing book. It combines both their books into a single book that is more readable. You can read it on a plain flight: https://leanpub.com/agiletesting-condensed

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael! I know this book and I have this book, one hint: My recommendation for exploratory testing is the book from Elisabeth Hendrickson" Explore it!